# generating bit number from 0.0 to X.7 - python

Tags: python, byte, bit

I would like to generate bit address with python, starting from 0.0 and ends at X.7.

How to build a function which will increase BYTE number when BIT address goes above X.7?

Example:

```
Input = 0.7 + 0.1 (0.8)  >> Output = 1.0

Input = 1.7 + 0.1 (1.8)  >>  Output = 2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your internal representation can be some non-negative integer number of bits:

```
>>> 7 + 1
8

>>> 15 + 1
16
```

Then you can convert that to the dotted format whenever you need a string representation:

```py
def format_bit_address(bit):
    return f"{bit // 8}.{bit % 8}"
```

```py
>>> format_bit_address(7)
'0.7'
>>> format_bit_address(1)
'0.1'
>>> format_bit_address(7 + 1)
'1.0'
```